# Calculate 9:00 PM in between two dates in python

Tags: python, datetime

How can I calculate how many times 9:00 PM can come in between two dates?

```
dt_start_time = "2014-09-23 11:00:00"
dt_end_time   = "2014-09-24 12:00:00"
```

Expected Output is 1

```
dt_start_time = "2014-09-24 09:00:00"
dt_end_time   = "2014-09-24 22:00:00"
```

Expected Output 1

```
dt_start_time = "2014-09-24 09:00:00"
dt_end_time   = "2014-09-26 12:00:00"
```

Expected Output 2

Comment: It is not clear, do you need to calculate number of days between two dates?

Comment: Why the expected output in the last example is 2 and not 3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: @liya No, I need to calculate how many times 9:00 PM can come in between two dates.

Comment: @TomRon, its 2, because there will be only two 9:00 PM i.e

2014-09-24 21:00:00
2014-09-25 21:00:00

Comment: @Cyber, Its not about converting string into datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply by converting the time difference between the two dates to days, and add an extra day if the dates range misses an extra 9 PM because of roundoff

```
dt_start_time = "2014-09-23 11:00:00"
dt_end_time = "2014-09-24 23:00:00"

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

from datetime import datetime as dt

st = dt.strptime(dt_start_time, format)
end = dt.strptime(dt_end_time, format)

count = (end - st).days
if st.hour < 21 and end.hour >= 21:
    count += 1
print count
```

Comment: @Anurag Your expected output for 2nd casse is wrong, how can you have 9PM between 9AM and 12 noon on same day? The result should be 0, and that is what I output..

Comment: Agree, second case is wrong. Have updated, Thanks :-)